# How to find remaining time using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, datetime

```
{
  publishDateTime: "2021-07-31T13:53:51.653",
  duration: 3
}
```

I want to find the remaining days this event is going to close. Here the duration is how many days this event is live.

**Remaining time**

```
20:40:02
Ends tomorrow at 12:00 pm
```

It should be in this format.

Comment: SO is not a coding service - what have you tried? - also, how is `2021-07-31T13:53:51.653` at all `tomorrow at 12:00 pm` - can you explain why "it ends" 1hour 53 minutes 51.653 seconds early?

Comment: search 1: javascript date add days

Comment: search 2: mdn date functions

Comment: Search 3: find `date-fns` and enjoy the rest of your day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setInterval and clearInterval functions for this purpose. You would have to create a function to do this. Luckily I had a basic code template for the same.

Given the endtime is provided by the user or publishDateTime in your case

```js
function timer(endTime = "Aug 16 2021 20:00:00 GMT+0530") { //accept from user
  const second = 1000,
    minute = second * 60,
    hour = minute * 60,
    day = hour * 24;

  let end = new Date(endTime).getTime(),
    x = setInterval(function () {

      let now = new Date().getTime(),
        timeLeft = end - now;

      let days = Math.floor(timeLeft / (day)),
        hours = Math.floor((timeLeft % (day)) / (hour)),
        minutes = Math.floor((timeLeft % (hour)) / (minute)),
        seconds = Math.floor((timeLeft % (minute)) / second);

      console.log('Time left:' + days + "Days " + hours + "Hrs " + minutes + "Mins " + seconds + "secs")

      if (timeLeft < 0) {
        console.log('Times up');
        clearInterval(x);
      }
    }, 1000)                    // time refresh in ms
}

timer("Aug 3 2021 20:00:00 GMT+0530")
```